# run method from button in dialog

Tags: android

I have a dialog that pops up on a button press from the action bar. In the dialog there is a layout with a few buttons. one one of the buttons I am just trying to call a simple method on that displays a toast, just to show that it is working.

this is the method that comes from the initial button that displays the dialog:

```
public void optionsPressed(MenuItem item){
    final Dialog optionsDialog = new Dialog(this);
    optionsDialog.setTitle("Options");
    optionsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.options);
    optionsDialog.show();



}
```

and here is part of the layout with the button that I am trying to use to display the toast:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF66"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="FFFF66" />
```

and lastly this is just the method I am trying to call from the onClick above:

```
public void paintClicked(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Color selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I am trying to put some more important code in this method rather than just a toast but for now, after debugging my app isnt even making it back to the paintClicked method and im not sure why?

```
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method paintClicked(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3825)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: paintClicked [class android.view.View]
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-26 12:12:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(17686):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please share your logcat too; Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an ID to your button and then do this:

```
Button button1;
button1 =(Button)optionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Color selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

put your code from the paintClicked method in the onclicklistener.

An example of doing this in the method: (I have not tested this):

```
public void optionsPressed(MenuItem item){
    final Dialog optionsDialog = new Dialog(this);
    optionsDialog.setTitle("Options");
    View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.options, null);
    button1 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Color selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    optionsDialog .setContentView(dialogView);
    optionsDialog .show();
}
```

Comment: well then should declare the dialog as static? rather than inside of the method where i did?

Comment: still wont work, this breaks the app for some reason

Comment: edited my answer, if this stil doesn't work please post your error log!

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:onClick="paintClicked"
```

this searchs for  `paintClicked` in the current activity, if you have this method in a fragment or a dialog it will not find it. So: use the typical setOnClickListener() and implement there your function or move this function to the activity (not recommended)